# loading RProvider in F#

Tags: r, f#, package, installation, type-providers

I'm still a noob with F#, and I don't understand all the syntax and logic for loading and using packages.

For example, i would like to use (Blue Mountain's) RProvider.
http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/index.html

Using VS2015, in my current solution, I've installed the package with the PM console and `Install-Package RProvider`

I modified a bit the RProvider.fsx because I've got newer versions of R.NET Community

```
#nowarn "211"
// Standard NuGet or Paket location
#I "."
#I "lib/net40"

// Standard NuGet locations for R.NET
#I "../R.NET.Community.1.6.4/lib/net40"
#I "../R.NET.Community.FSharp.0.1.9/lib/net40"

// Standard Paket locations for R.NET
#I "../R.NET.Community/lib/net40"
#I "../R.NET.Community.FSharp.1.6.4/lib/net40"

// Try various folders that people might like
#I "bin"
#I "../bin"
#I "../../bin"
#I "lib"
#I "../packages"

// Reference RProvider and RDotNet 
#r "RDotNet.dll"
#r "RDotNet.FSharp.dll"
#r "RProvider.dll"
#r "RProvider.Runtime.dll"

open RProvider
do fsi.AddPrinter(fun (synexpr:RDotNet.SymbolicExpression) -> synexpr.Print())
```

Now my questions are

1) how to load a package (RProvider) from F# interactive ?
well actually i managed to do it this way
For example the RProvider.fsx file is in the path
C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford\packages\RProvider.1.1.15\RProvider.fsx

what i did is

```
#I @"C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford";;
#load "packages\RProvider.1.1.15\RProvider.fsx";;
```

and it works :-)
but can I avoid writing the whole path ?

2) In VS2015 if I want to include it in a solution... 
in the solution explorer i have included the RProvider.fsx file (below AssemblyInfo.fs, App.config and packages.config come after, is this right ?)
and last the program itself Rtype.fs

I'm trying to reproduce the example from 
http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/FSharpRProvider/Statistics-QuickStart.html

```
open System
open *RDotNet* // the namespace or module 'RDotNet' is not defined
open *RProvider*
open *RProvider*.graphics
open RProvider.stats 

// let x = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory
// val x : string

printfn "hello world"

Console.ReadKey() |> ignore

// Random number generator
let rng = Random()
let rand () = rng.NextDouble()

// Generate fake X1 and X2 
let X1s = [ for i in 0 .. 9 -> 10. * rand () ]
let X2s = [ for i in 0 .. 9 -> 5. * rand () ]

// Build Ys, following the "true" model
let Ys = [ for i in 0 .. 9 -> 5. + 3. * X1s.[i] - 2. * X2s.[i] + rand () ]

let dataset =
    namedParams [
        "Y", box Ys;
        "X1", box X1s;
        "X2", box X2s; ]
    |> R.data_frame

let result = R.lm(formula = "Y~X1+X2", data = dataset)
let coefficients = result.AsList().["coefficients"].AsNumeric()
let residuals = result.AsList().["residuals"].AsNumeric()
let summary = R.summary(result)
*summary.AsList().["r.squared"].AsNumeric()
R.plot result*
```

//this expression should have type 'unit' but has type 'NumericVector'...

I'm getting some warnings/errors by Intellisense although the compiler managed a build.
When executing the exe, it looks like the windows screen is busy, i manage to see some graphs, but they look like they have got nothing to do with what Rtype.fs is saying...

thanks for helping !

**EDIT**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would not recommend using a different version of R.NET than the one that RProvider installs automatically as a dependency. The loading is a bit fragile and it might break things.

1) Regarding the path, you should be able to pass relative path to `#load`, so just dropping the `#I` from your script should do the trick.

2) When referencing a dependency from a project (rather than from a script file), you need to add a dependency to the project references. In Visual Studio, this is done by right click on the "References" in your project and using "Add Reference". For type providers, you also need to click "Enable" when the reference is loaded.

Comment: I have added screenshots. I think the R.NET package was installed altogether with RProvider. So there would be a discrepancy between the version installed by NuGET and the version referenced by RProvider.fsx which is downloaded with it. Also, in my screenshot i can see RProvider in References, but i don't remember clicking on "Enable" anytime. when i see the properties of RProvider, i see nothing looking like a tick box

Comment: You should see something like this: https://rodhern.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/3-tpwarning_thumb.png?w=604&h=251

Comment: In Options dialog, make sure the provider is enabled (box checked): http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxqd2.png